# function() : this(null) {}

Tags: c#, syntax, constructor, null, class-constructors

Can someone please explain the following syntactic sugar?

```
protected MyConstructor() : this(null)
```

Mainly I am interested in this part: "`: this(null)`"

I know how protected, constructors and "this" keyword work, but am confused and cannot find any detailed information of the last part all put-together in all my online searches.

Edit: I should add that it is in a public abstract class. So I guess the constructor is calling the implementers constructor.

Thanks

Comment: Guess is that it calls another constructor and passes in the value null. Is there a constructor that takes one parameter?

Comment: Did you debug the code to try to see what would happen?

Comment: By the way - if you are familiar with the "constructor() : base()" syntax, this should look familiar. Instead of calling the super class constructor this calls the constructor in the current class.

Comment: Look into [constructor overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

Comment: There's no sugar there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It calls another class constructor that has a parameter:

```
protected MyConstructor() : this(null) { }  // This calls the other constructor

protected MyConstructor(object whatever)
{
    Frob(whatever);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a special syntax for constructors. You can have two basic variants:

```
protected MyConstructor() : this(null)
```

Calls the different overload of the constructor with the `null` parameter.

```
protected MyConstructor() : base(null)
```

Calls the constructor on a base class with the `null` parameter.

So, you can have a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
  object someObject;

  public MyClass() : this(null) {}
  public MyClass(object someObject) { this.someObject = someObject; }
}
```

Now you can instantiate the class like this:

```
var c = new MyClass(); // c.someObject is null
var c2 = new MyClass(new object()); // c2.someObject is some new object instance
```

This is required because you can't reuse constructor code in any other way. If you were just overriding or overloading a method, the equivalent would look like this:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
  DoStuff(null);
}

public void DoStuff(object someObject)
{
  // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Just for kicks, I'll note you can write the last example as: `public void DoStuff(object someObject = null) { // Do some stuff }`

Comment: @MikeChristensen True, but with one important distinction - optional parameters are determined at compile time. So if you have a library, that changes an optional parameter's default value, the change will not propagate to users of the library until they recompile. That's because optional parameters aren't actually a feature of the IL, they're just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 5):

There is *another* constructor on that same object, which takes some sort of *nullable* object.  For example:

```
public MyConstructor(string str)
{
   // A
}


public MyConstructor() : this(null)
{
   // B
}
```

In this example (changing constructors to `public` for demonstration purposes), if I call:

```
var newObj = new MyConstructor();
```

It will create a `MyConstructor` object, run the code in `A` first (passing in `null` as the parameter) then run the code in `B` next.

This is a way of allowing you to consolidate common code that needs to run regardless of what constructor is called.

Answer (score 3):

What `this(null)` is doing is calling another constructor in the same class that takes one parameter, and passing a null value as that parameter. Look into `constructor overloading` for more info. Also, `constructor chaining` is more pertinent to your question, but I'd look into both topics.